# Discrete primal-duality in optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, duality, integer-programming

I would like to inquire about the existence of something perhaps similar to the duality theorem in the convex analysis or convex programming in the discrete setting. Here is a concrete example.

Let $D\times E\times F\subseteq \mathbb {\overline{Z^-}}^3$, $S$ be an index set. There exists 3 functions: $D\times E\times S\to F$, $E\times F\times S\to D$ and $F\times D\times S\to E$. Consider the following 3 formulae.

1. $$\sup_{s\in S}f(d,e,s)=\sup_{s\in S}f(d-1,e-1,s)+\sup_{s\in S}f(d-1,e,s), \,\forall (d-1,e-1)\in\mathbb N^2.$$
2. $$\inf_{s\in S}d(e,f,s) = 1+\inf_{s\in S,i\in[0,f]}\big(\max(d(e-1,i,s),d(e,f-i,s))\big), \,\forall (e-1,f)\in\mathbb {\overline{Z^-}}^2.$$
3. $$\inf_{s\in S}e(f,d,s) = \inf_{s\in S,i\in[0,f]}\big(\max(e(i,d-1,s)+1,e(f-i,d-1,s))\big), \,\forall (f,d-1)\in\mathbb {\overline{Z^-}}^2.$$

I conjecture these 3 recursions are equivalent. How would one prove it? I suppose one either needs or generalize it to a discrete duality theorem as I have inquired at the beginning.

Comment: Downvoter: Would you care to explain your downvote?

Comment: Please have a look at K. Murota's book on *Discrete Convex Analysis* https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718508, it might contain relevant information for you!